# Start a Networkmanager GUI from Commandline

Tags: command-line, network-manager, configuration

I have setup a kiosk system, it uses `xorg`, `openbox` and `chromium-browser`. It is started via `systemd` like that:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.sh

[Unit]
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
User=kiosk
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startx
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and `/home/kiosk/.xsession`

```
#!/bin/sh

xset -dpms
xset s off

openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11

while true; do
  chromium-browser  --kiosk --no-first-run 'http://thepcspy.com'
done
```

That is working fine and the browser is started in fullscreen on boot, just as I like it. But now the client asks for the ability to configure the wireless networks. What I would like to do, is to fire up a network-manager window.

How can I start the network-manager in an additional window withing the existing openbox session from the commandline.

Basically I am going to setup a tiny password-protected nodejs server on localhost, which will run a shell script.

So right now I have such a tiny server and if executing this:

```
shell.exec('chromium-browser');
```

gives this error, if the server is started from the kiosk user:

```
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

And this one, if executed from somebody else:

```
(chromium-browser:6532): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:22:24.837: cannot open display: :0
exec: No protocol specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a kiosk setup I changed the way to trigger `wicd`. I added a udev rule which in turn triggered a script whenever a certain usb-stick was inserted. From there I wrote a unix timestamp to a specific file. Additionally I created a second bash script which monitored this file using the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki). That one was executed within the `.xsession` file.